# Confusing compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, linker, header-files

Ok If need be I will add the code but normally I am decent at figuring out errors. However this one I got is very confusing. I am using three files. A driver code citysim.cpp, and two supporting files utils.cpp and utils.h. I am guessing it stems from the fact I am doing something wrong when coordinating between them.

The error is as follows

```
g++ -g -Wall -o citysim citysim.o utils.o
utils.o: In function `map_of_cities::read(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/rryder1/cs302/labs/lab4/utils.cpp:95: multiple definition of `map_of_cities::read(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
citysim.o:/home/rryder1/cs302/labs/lab4/utils.h:61: first defined here
citysim.o: In function `map_of_cities::read(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
citysim.cpp:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `city::city()'
citysim.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
citysim.cpp:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
citysim.o: In function `std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> > >, city const&)':
citysim.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorI4citySaIS0_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS0_S2_EERKS0_[std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> > >, city const&)]+0xd2): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
citysim.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorI4citySaIS0_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS0_S2_EERKS0_[std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city, std::allocator<city> > >, city const&)]+0x27d): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
citysim.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<city>::destroy(city*)':
citysim.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorI4cityE7destroyEPS1_[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<city>::destroy(city*)]+0x18): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
citysim.o:citysim.cpp:(.text._ZSt8_DestroyI4cityEvPT_[void std::_Destroy<city>(city*)]+0x14): more undefined references to `city::~city()' follow
utils.o: In function `map_of_cities::read(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
utils.cpp:(.text+0xacd): undefined reference to `city::city()'
utils.cpp:(.text+0xc68): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
utils.cpp:(.text+0xcc7): undefined reference to `city::~city()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The one thing it may stem from is I am not sure how to link the utils.cpp with the utils.h or if i need to. I am used to writing everything in one cpp file. utils.cpp and citysim.cpp both have include statements for utils.h. utils.h basically just has the class definitions and function headers. the utils.cpp contains all of the function defintions and the citysim.cpp contains the main function.

Here is my utils.h file

```
#ifndef __CITY_DEFS_H__
#define __CITY_DEFS_H__

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//#include ALL HEADER FILES NEEDED FOR THIS HEADER FILE

class city {
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const city &);
  //OTHER FRIENDS
  friend class map_of_cities;
  public:
    city();
    ~city();

    // MEMBER FUNCTIONS
  protected:
    // MEMBER DATA

    string Name, type;
    float latitude, longitude;
    int population, listlocation;


    // MEMBER FUNCTIONS
};


ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const city &);

//OTHER CLASS DEFINITIONS
class map_of_cities {
    public:
        map_of_cities();
        ~map_of_cities();

        void read(string fname);
        float distance(city one, city two);
        void populatelists();
        void print();
        int listpop(vector<city> list);

    private:
        vector<city> cities;
        vector<city> local;
        vector<city> regional;
        vector<city> global;
};

#endif
```

If i need to include the other files I can but the utils.cpp is pretty big and would just be a mess to sift through. Is my problem in this?

Comment: More information is needed to address the underlying problem.

Comment: Can I take a guess that you put the body of `map_of_cities` in a header?

Comment: Sounds like you might need (amongst other things) to use include-guards in your `utils.h` file. Basically, it's a trick using `#ifdef` that prevents the file being included more than once. That should I imagine, solve your problem with multiple definitions.

Comment: Ok I added the header file if that helps narrow down the problem. Id appreciate any help especially if you can explain whats going wrong instead of just telling me the fix. Although Ill take the fix haha

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a compiler error, its a link error.   You don't have a constructor or destructor for the "city" class being linked. Make sure you include both cpp files when you run your c++ command, or separate out the linking stage to happen after you compile.

Building a C++ project involves several phases.  Two important phases are "compile" and "link".  The compiler takes each C++ file and produces an "object" file.  The object file contains all the defined symbols (classes, functions, methods, global variables, etc...).  Parts of the object file may reference other symbols that aren't in the original object file.

In your case, you'd have the `util` object file, which references `city::~city()` and `city::city()`.

In the compiling phase, the source code can also reference symbols that will be in another object. Typically .h files are used to provide information about the symbols, but usually they don't include the actual symbol itself.   In your case `util.h` spells out "This program as a city constructor and destructor", but it doesn't actually *provide* one.

As you said in your comment, you do indeed need to add them in "util.cpp", to provide an actual implementation that can be found by the linker.

Comment: Sorry can you explain this a little further. Ive never really dealt with linking so I have no clue what I am doing. I have a constructor and deconstructor in the utils.h file. Is it expecting me to also define them in the utils.cpp. Im guessing you may need to see my code to know for sure. I am using a make file to compile that was provided to me (this is for a class project but id like to learn whats really going on for my own use).

Comment: I've added more details. Hopefully that helps.